# Remove 1 Letter from String Value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a heap of string values being returned through a query. On some of them, there is a leading A-Z. Is it possible to detect a 1 letter word and remove it?

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
( 
 String varchar(100)    
)

INSERT INTO @T (String) VALUES
('A String Value'),
('B Stackoverflow'),
('Microsoft'),
('T Google, Yahoo')
```

Expected Results:

```
String Value
Stackoverflow
Microsoft
Google, Yahoo
```

How could this be done?

Comment: Presence of a space in character 2...write a query like that?

Comment: Sorry @Ctznkane525 I don't understand your point.

Comment: Well, the logic is pretty simple. You want the substring starting at 3 in CASEs WHEN the second character is a space and starting at 1 otherwise, for the length of the string. Are you familiar with functions like `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` and `CASE` expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CHARINDEX()`, `LTRIM()` and `SUBSTRING()` like

```
SELECT LTRIM(SUBSTRING(String, CHARINDEX(' ', String), LEN(String))) Result
FROM @T;
```

Or by detecting if the second char is a whiteSpace or not (which is better)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(String, CASE WHEN
                              CHARINDEX(' ', String) = 2
                              THEN 3
                              ELSE 1 END, LEN(String) ) Result
FROM @T;
```

You can also replace `CASE` with `IIF()` funtion if you are working on 2012+ version like

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(String, IIF(CHARINDEX(' ', String) = 2, 3, 1), LEN(String) ) Result
FROM @T;
```

**Returns:**

```
+---------------+
|    Result     |
+---------------+
| String Value  |
| Stackoverflow |
| Microsoft     |
| Google, Yahoo |
+---------------+
```

Comment: The t in microsoft got truncated lol. You'd need to add a case for when there is no space or it'll start at char 0 and skip a character at the end (because it'll traverse from 0 to len(string) - 1)

Comment: Thanks @Sami, I just saw you regularly updating it so I thought I would wait. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `like` to match a pattern consisting of one letter, one space, and zero or more additional characters to determine if the string needs to be shortened. Once the determination is made you can use `Stuff`, `Substring` or `Right` and `Len` to remove the first two characters.

```
select String,
  case when String like '[A-Z] %' then Stuff( String, 1, 2, '' ) else String end as ShorterString
  from @T;
```